# Code signing in Mac with Perl scripts compiled with PAR::Packer fails

Tags: python, macos, perl, sign

Does anyone have experience getting compiled Perl binaries to code sign on OSX? When trying to compile a Perl script in PAR, it returns an error when I try to code sign it. I've gotten around this error by not trying to code sign it as a binary (e.g., inside the "Resources" folder within a .app), but if I put it in the proper MacOS directory it fails on the signature.

I've seen numerous fixes for python scripts (https://github.com/kamillus/py2app-pyqt-codesign-fix-os-x), but not any for Perl!

The error message reported by codesign -s is "main executable failed strict validation". I've tried the --deep option as well with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out how to fix this. It's a solution that I adapted based on the Python solution written here:

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Recipe-OSX-Code-Signing

It's a problem caused by the Mach-O headers. Hopefully this helps someone else. After running this python script on the PAR executable, it will codesign.

Some modifications are still required to PAR to get this to run, however, since PAR looks for the `\nPAR.pm\n` signature at the end of the file... which now contains the code signature. I have a working solution for that as well, and can share if others are interested.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function

import os
import sys

from macholib._cmdline import main as _main
from macholib.MachO import MachO
from macholib.mach_o import *

ARCH_MAP={
    ('<', '64-bit'): 'x86_64',
    ('<', '32-bit'): 'i386',
    ('>', '64-bit'): 'ppc64',
    ('>', '32-bit'): 'ppc',
}

def print_file(fp, path):
    print(path, file=fp)
    exe_data = MachO(path)

    for header in exe_data.headers:
        seen = set()
        if header.MH_MAGIC == MH_MAGIC_64:
            sz = '64-bit'
        else:
            sz = '32-bit'

        arch = CPU_TYPE_NAMES.get(header.header.cputype,
                header.header.cputype)

        print('    [%s endian=%r size=%r arch=%r]' % (header.__class__.__name__,
                header.endian, sz, arch), file=fp)
        for idx, name, other in header.walkRelocatables():
            if other not in seen:
                seen.add(other)
                print('\t' + other, file=fp)
    print('', file=fp)

    cmds = exe_data.headers[0].commands  # '0' - Exe contains only one architecture.
    file_size = exe_data.headers[0].size

    linkedit = cmds[3][1] # __LINKEDIT
    new_segsize = file_size - linkedit.fileoff
    linkedit.filesize = new_segsize

    alignment = 4096
    linkedit.vmsize = new_segsize + (alignment - (new_segsize % alignment)) # alignment

    data = cmds[4][1] # LC_SYMTAB
    new_strsize = file_size - data.stroff
    data.strsize = new_strsize

    # Write changes back.
    fp = open(exe_data.filename, 'rb+')
    exe_data.write(fp)
    fp.close()

    print ("Successfully modified headers.\n")

def main():
    _main(print_file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        sys.exit(main())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

Comment: I tried this script with an executable created with PAR/pp but it fires the following error: File "python_prepare_codesign.py", line 67, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "python_prepare_codesign.py", line 63, in main
_main(print_file)

Comment: That is a python error, you're running something incorrectly or didn't import the modules using pip. That being said, this code will only work for universal binary (32 & 64-bit) architectures, since there are some changes for 64-bit only binaries.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I missed a module (however the script breaks out, probably because the executable has the wrong architecture?). We are using a 64-bit binary. Do not know if using universal binaries makes much sense nowadays or it is possible to compile our application like that. Have you ever solved the issue also on 64-bit binaries? I've been scanning the web all week with no success.

Comment: Universal binaries don't make much sense anymore; in fact, Apple is requiring 64-bit only for the AppStore. Yes, I solved the issue, but it took a lot of investment and creativity and can't share it here on SO.

Comment: Please, write to me in private mail (added now to profile) or give me your contact so that we can discuss it professionally.